# No funciona instanciar clase en php en el hosting 000webHost

Tags: php

Tengo un problema con mi pagina web que esta alojada en el hosting de 000webhost. El dominio es https://varma-eirl.000webhostapp.com/
Estoy usando MVC, el problema es que cuando quiero mostrar la tabla productos no se muestra, al parecer el problema esta cuando instancio la clase para poder ejecutar el metodo que me retorna los datos de la tabla producto. Hice una prueba con var_dump hacia la instancia, pero no me arroja ningun resultado.

```
class jvega{
    private $db;
    private $producto;
     public function __construct(){
        $db=new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "password", "bd");
         $this->db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
         $this->producto= array();  }

         public function lista_producto()
    {
      $consulta=$this->db->query("select id_producto,nombre,precio_venta,stock,estado,imagen from PRODUCTO");
        while($row=$consulta->fetch_assoc()){
          $this->producto[]=$row;
        }

        return $this->producto;

    }
```

Este es el modelo, cambie los parametros del usuario y password en mi hosting si estan puestos y funcionando, la base de datos si conecta, ya hice las pruebas.

```
<?php

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/modelo/model.php');
$vega= new jvega();
 $lista_producto=$vega->lista_producto();

 ?>
```

Este es el controlador, al parecer el problema esta aqui ya que la inclusion del modelo si funciona, pero al momento de instanciar la clase no funciona nada despues.

```
<?php

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/vista/cabecera.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/controlador/controlador.php');

?>
<label style="position:absolute;top:350px;left:250px;font-size:30"> LISTA PRODUCTOS</label>
<table style="position:absolute;top:400px;left:300px;width:1000px;text-align:left;border-collapse:collapse;background-color:white;">
<thead>
<tr>
    <td>Codigo</td>
    <td>Nombre</td>
    <td>Precio Venta</td>
    <td>Stock</td>
    <td>Estado</td>
    <td>Imagen</td>
</tr>
</thead>

<?php

foreach($lista_producto as $p)
{
    echo "<tr>
        <td>{$p['id_producto']}</td>
        <td>{$p['nombre']}</td>
        <td>{$p['precio_venta']}</td>
        <td>{$p['stock']}</td>
        <td>{$p['estado']}</td>
    </tr>";
}
?>


</table>


</html>
```

Y este es mi archivo producto en donde quiero mostrar la tabla productos, actualmente solo me muestra la cabecera, luego cuando incluyo el controlador para obtener los datos de la tabla producto no funciona.https://varma-eirl.000webhostapp.com/vista/productos.php ese es link de mi archivo producto.

Comment: As intentado activar los errores? Agregando `error_reporting(E_ALL);` al inicio del codigo para ver lo que realmente esta pasando?

Comment: aver lo intentare

Comment: ya vi el error amigo, me sale error en el modelo, en la linea de set names utf 8(no se porque, pero la borrare xD). Gracias